# Gmail api for localhost

Tags: wordpress, plugins, localhost, gmail-api

I have installed WordPress in my localhost. For sign up verification, I installed wp smtp mail plug in. I want to send mail via gmail. For that I need api client ID and client secret. But when I visit Google developer console, then I found that I can't use my localhost website for that.

My question: how can I get gmail api for WordPress wp smtp mail plug in. (For localhost:port)

Sorry for bad English. Hope you understand :)

Answer (score 0):

There is popular plugin for Gmail:

[Gmail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gmail-smtp/)

> [Gmail SMTP](https://wphowto.net/gmail-smtp-plugin-for-wordpress-1341) plugin allows you to authenticate with your Gmail account to send email via Gmail SMTP server.
>   [image]

Comment: No, but you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose your localhost to the internet and  allow Gmail to authorize it.

Comment: Thanks. But i will do serveo, because it let me create sub domain that ngrok won't let me do. By the way, thanks again.

Comment: Not working for localhost for me,error 400,cant authenticate.

Comment: The answer was sent two years ago... I'd suggest to ask question again. .

Comment: I have some limit for questions buddy. @Yasen